# Disable charger beep ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, charging

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop, which runs perfectly. But I am having trouble with the charging feature. The charging is constantly being interrupted, stopping and restarting, with an associated beeping that is quite annoying. It plays through where ever the system sound is playing out of, either main system speakers or headphones, rather than any internal system beeper. Is it possible to disable this sound? I checked the bios, no options to turn this off in there.

I am unsure whether the charging interrupts is due to a faulty power cable (I have ordered a new one) or some software related issue. It seems to happen quite frequently when booting up new programs, or if I have multiple programs open at once, which makes me think it might be software related. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: does this disappear if you set the slider in Volume Settings in System Sounds all the way to the left to effectively mute it?

Comment: System sounds is muted in the settings. After having a further play around with the laptop, the issue does seen to be related to the amount of load on the system. If I pump graphics settings up on some games, charging stops and starts almost constantly. If I lower them back down it stops

Answer (score 1):

Install PulseAudioVolume and turn off system sounds. That will do the trick.

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
pavucontrol
```